# How to overlap the Nav bar instead of pushing content to right?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, nav

I'm using the same code in my website. Is there any way open the nav bar and overlap on right, without pushing content to right?
https://codepen.io/dalisc/pen/qzRGxQ

I experimented with position and z-index, but didn't help. Thank you

```
<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar" onmouseover="toggleSidebar()" onmouseout="toggleSidebar()">
    <div class="navContent">
  <a href="#">YOUR DASHBOARD</a><br>
  <a href="#">MESSAGE CENTER</a><br>
  <a href="#">IMPACT & OUTCOMES</a><br>
  <a href="#">LEARNERS</a><br>
  <a href="#">PROGRAMS</a>
  <a href="#">SETTINGS</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.sidebar {
        height: 100%;
        width: 85px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: #181633;
        transition: 0.5s;
        padding-top: 120px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow-x: hidden;
}
.sidebar a {
        padding: 3px 8px 3px 32px;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #D3D2E4;
        display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "85px";` instead of `document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";`

```js
var mini = true;

function toggleSidebar() {
  if (mini) {
    //console.log("opening sidebar");
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
    /*change this line*/
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "85px";
    /*change this line*/
    this.mini = false;
  } else {
    //console.log("closing sidebar");
    document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "85px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "85px";
    this.mini = true;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 85px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  transition: 0.5s;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

main .sidebar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.material-icons,
.icon-text {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.material-icons {
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}

#main {
  padding: 16px;
  margin-left: 85px;
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidebar a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

<div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar" onmouseover="toggleSidebar()" onmouseout="toggleSidebar()">
  <a href="#"><span><i class="material-icons">info</i><span class="icon-text">about</span></a><br>
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">spa</i><span class="icon-text"></span>services</a></span>
  </a><br>
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i><span class="icon-text"></span>clients</span></a><br>
  <a href="#"><i class="material-icons">email</i><span class="icon-text"></span>contact<span></a>
</div>

<div id="main">
  <h2>Open/Collapse Sidebar on Hover</h2>
  <p>Hover over any part of the sidebar to open the it.</p>
  <p>To close the sidebar, move your mouse out of the sidebar.</p>
</div>
```

codepen [here](https://codepen.io/Ev1ltw1n/pen/RwgmMvq)